# Unity 3D: Newtonsoft.json does not work in build. What can I do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, json.net, game-engine

I am doing a project on AI car using Unity 3D. Unity sends car related data to a python client, python client processes the data and sends steering and acceleration value. I initialize all car data in a class, then using JsonConvert.SerializeObject() from Newtonsoft.json(Json.net) I convert it into a json string and send the string through a normal socket.

This process works fine in editor mode, but for the build json parsing does not work. I have added the Newtonsoft.json.dll in unity Assets/Plugins. It still does not work. In player settings, I have tried both dot net 4.6 and 3.5 as script runtime version and 4.6/2.0 subset for API compatibility with no success.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Which version of .NET does the Newtonsoft.json.dll use? It is possible that it uses a version greater than 4.6.

Comment: which scripting backend are you using? it could be that on build it is stripping your model classes because they are not implicitly used in code.

Comment: your build is win32 /64? you need to copy the dll to same folder that the executable

Comment: @joreldraw, my build is in win32 while my machine is win64. My build exe in the desktop folder. So shall I copy the dll there?

Comment: @turnipinrut, I am using c# mono for scripting.

Comment: @IanH, I also think this might be the problem. I am trying see if that is the problem.

Comment: @turnipinrut, I have declared those model class as Serializable and internal class, scripting backend is set to mono. Is it ok?

Comment: Yes , copy dll to exe folder

Comment: There is a Unity version for Newtonjson. See duplicate for more info